# Auto adjust margin-top of main content section based on variable hight fixed header

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, shopify

https://g7uuvt72cje7i7gh-26803830855.shopifypreview.com/ (mobile view)
At the moment I have that .main-content has a margin-top based on the sticky-animate, that puts the header fixed on top on mobile. Point is, as you can see, there is a div that can be closed with the X, variating the height. This does not change the margin, leaving a pretty bad space.
The java used is:

```js
if (jQuery(window).width() < 425) {
$(function(){
    $('.main-content').each(function(){
        var headerHeight=$('.sticky-animate').height();
        // headerHeight+=15; // maybe add an offset too?
        $(this).css('margin-top',headerHeight+'px');
    });
});
}
```

Anyone can help me improve this in a way that it adapts?
The script that works on the hide bar is:

```js
function Hide(HideID) 
{
  HideID.style.display = "none"; 
}
```

```html
  <div id="right-showing">
    <a href="#" onclick="Hide(Bar);">X</a>
  </div>
```

Hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you want to re-run the header height function when the bar is closed.

I restructured your code a bit to avoid duplication.

Try something like this:

```
function setMargin(index, element) {
    var headerHeight=$('.sticky-animate').height();
    $(element).css('margin-top',headerHeight+'px');
}

if (jQuery(window).width() < 425) {
    $(function(){
        $('.main-content').each(setMargin);
    });
}

function Hide(HideID) 
{
    HideID.style.display = "none";
    $('.main-content').each(setMargin);
}
```

Comment: Tried, but nope, doesn't adapt.

Comment: @MorganPubblicita I updated the answer. Can you please try again?